# Template Specialization not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T, size_t... i>
class Bar{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Foo{};

template<typename T1, size_t... i1>
template<typename T2, size_t... i2>
struct Foo<Bar<T1,i1...>,Bar<T2,i2...>>
{
    struct Eq {};
};
```

As you see, there is a variadic type `Bar<T,size_t...>` and a type `Foo<T1,T2>`. Foo has a specialization in case that two `Bar`s are used as its template parameters. This specialization has an inner type `Eq`.

However, the following does not work:

```
typename Foo<Bar<int,2>,Bar<int,3>>::Eq b;
```

It tells that there is no type `Eq` in `Foo<Bar<int,2>,Bar<int,3>>`, i.e., the compiler does not pick the template specialization but the base definition of `Foo<T1,T2>` which indeed has no inner `Eq` type.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does the compiler not pick the specialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of double template argument list:

```
template<typename T1, size_t... i1>
template<typename T2, size_t... i2>
```

Change to:

```
template<typename T1, size_t... i1, typename T2, size_t... i2>
```